# Name lookup timed out - Curl issue with Wordpress on MAMP

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, mamp

Have a strange issue with Curl on MAMP.
When trying to update plugins or Wordpress core — it's causing issue with curl transport: `Name lookup timed out`

CURL enabled in my PHP on MAMP

- `cURL support    enabled`
- `cURL Information    7.43.0`

Tested this issue with 2 latest MAMP versions.

Any ideas? What could be the problem?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you access https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/update-check/1.1/ from a browser or do you get a DNS error?

Comment: @drew010 hmm, i've got an `error`. This means that the problem is in DNS? I'm also tried to access that link from my IOS device using mobile network(with turned off wifi). And got `error` again.